# непрерывный путь в файле PLT

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, графы, 2d, вектор

Любой файл PLT- есть таблица пар координат отрезков. Содержит строку **PU X Y** (поднять перо и переместиться в координату X Y) и следом **PD X Y** (опустить перо и переместиться в точку X Y). Эти пары в фале "лежат", достаточно случайно, так как   на их последовательность влияет - последовательность редактирования (черчения). Дуги и окружности "лежат" достаточно последовательно (PD x y, PD x y, ..PD..PD) т.е . там нет **PU**. Плоттеры рисуют окружности и дуги непрерывно, а вот отрезки прямых в достаточно случайном порядке. В конце концов рисунок будет нарисован весь...
Есть крайняя необходимость написать алгоритм перезаписи всего PLT файла так, чтобы плоттер не поднимал пера... и возвращался в исходную точку. При этом нужно "**дописывать отрезки возврата**" которых в первичной таблице нет вообще. В точках ветвления выбираем каждый раз - "левый поворот". Получается что-то среднее между алгоритмом выхода из лабиринта и задачей коммивояжёра..
Прошу помочь с кодом: открыть файл -> проанализировать -> переписать -> показать на экране путь прохождения (с "ползунком" скорости визуализации)- > сохранить новый файл. Всяки метОды ручного рисования замкнутых полилиний или пошаговой "склейки" точек в рисовалках  - не подходят принципиально, так как файлы мои бывают оч. бОльшинькими!! Это не ручная работа...вернее такая ручная работа - не работа!

Comment: Уже после второй строчки возникает желание бросить читать Ваш текст. Если Вы хотите помощи, то нужно экономить время людей, которые используют форум для взаимной помощи. Вам нужно, избегая лишних слов и подробностей не относящихся к делу, математически сформулировать Вашу проблему.

Comment: Да! краткость - сестра не моего таланта! Что же мне делать "убогому"? Как же жить то с таким непомерным словарным запасом?...По-мне так: очень кратко описано. Как девчонки говорят: "..только программеры, да кодеры  соревнуются - у кого короче!" Ну и бросил бы читать не со второй, а с первой строчки.

Comment: "...Что же мне делать..." - переписать в краткой и понятной форме. У Вашего вопроса 16 просмотров. Вы можете конечно оставить все как есть - дело Ваше, но в таком случае вряд ли кто на этом форуме будет вникать в Вашу проблему. Ваш вопрос перегружен подробностями.